# how to decrease the space between links in mobile navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

I want to decrease the space between my links, but it's automatically setting room between them and won't let me change the space no matter what I do.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  #menu-btn {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .header .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #13131a;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .header .navbar a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a class="logo" asp-action="Index">
    <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" width="60" alt="logo" />
  </a>
  <div class="navbar nav">
    <a asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    <a href="#products">Products</a>
    <a href="#about">About Us</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping "></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass "></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket "></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars " id="menu-btn"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="search-form">
    <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="جستجو..." />
    <label for="search-box" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></label>
  </div>
</header>
```

I tried to change the margin and padding, but it still has that large space between the links.
I think the problem is something about the height.
here is the image of it:

[image]

Comment: Try to declare a correct class. Then changing the value of your *margin* and *padding*  from ```.header .navbar a``` in your css will resolve your problem.

Comment: what do you mean by correct classes?

Comment: I think they means .nav > a { margin: ; padding: ; }

Comment: As @David Henson said, you need to recreate your css to fix that spaces. Or you should change that *margin* and *padding* to **line-height** and set around *2.5rem* ```line-height:2.5rem;``` then you can see their difference. You can also try the answer of @Johannes below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set `flex-direction` and `justify-content` for your `.navbar`. These should be `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: flex-start` to place all items at the top of a column, i.e. directly above each other.